# Comparing datetimes of different formats in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to compare two dates in Python of different formats. Meaning, the "dates" can be of format "%d %H:%M:%S", "%H:%M:%S" or even "%M:%S". 
Initially i am working with datetimes of format "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y".
When i am trying to do as explained above i get the error:

```
ValueError: time data '5:37:52' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'
```

Which indeed is a logical error to get.
But are there any method or built in function in python that can handle different datetime formats? Or even a workaround?

I am using Python 2.7.12.
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You probably want the third-party [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library, which does generic parsing of date strings.

Comment: I presume `5:37:52` is just a time, so do you have some dates and times, and some just times?

Comment: Yes, i have some "times" which are just minutes and seconds, and some "dates" that are days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, i will check the dateutil library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
print( parse( "5:37:52" ) )
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 6, 5, 37, 52)
```

As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman%20Daniel) pointed out the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library will parse dates in various formats, so you just need to pass all your date strings through it in order to get the datetime objects

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This works in my case. Also thank you Daniel Roseman for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dateutil.parser.parse`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) to parse your time/date strings :

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse("12 05:37:52")
# datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 12, 5, 37, 52)
parse("05:37:52")
# datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 6, 5, 37, 52)
```